# Unable to find git in your PATH. With Git and Flutter PATH declared

Tags: windows, flutter, git, dart, path

I've been trying to fix this problem since yesterday and nothing seems to work so I can work with dart/flutter.
This is where everything is installed

- Flutter folder is installed on C:/
- Git is on C:\Program Files\Git

And on my PATH is all of this:

- C:\flutter\bin
- C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe (Tried as well without the "\git.exe" part and it didn't work either)
- C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
- C:\Windows\System32
- C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

[image: Everything on my User Variables PATH]

I've already tried to restart pc, add PATH according to other people having similar problems, separating the routes of the PATH with just "*;*" like:

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32...

Neither removing the git.exe work from:

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe

I tried to use both methods,

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe

and

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Also tried to reinstall flutter and git, but it didn't work either.

Tried a few minutes ago with the path on the System variables, it didn´t work either:
[image: Path on System Variables]

This is what happens when I run the flutter doctor command:

`C:\flutter> flutter doctor`

`Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.`

Comment: Could you post something more? E.g results of the "flutter doctor" and "git status" commands.

Comment: "_C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe_" you don't put executables in the path. and this looks like a question post typo. Your screenshot shows "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" instead. Please [edit] to clarify which it is

Comment: Flutter doctor shows the same thing, that git couldn´t be found my path. can you tell me how to run the git statuts? @itsMike

Comment: I tried both, with the git.exe on the route, and without it. @user

Comment: Follow this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75921194/flutter-on-windows-unable-to-find-git-in-your-path-if-terminal-is-not-in-admi) it should fix your problem.