# Flutter on Windows: "Unable to find git in your PATH" if terminal is not in admin mode

Tags: windows, flutter, git, path-variables

I eventually solved this issue (see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123995)) but wanted to share it here so that more people see it.

Issue is that after installing Flutter on Windows, you try to run flutter doctor and get '`Unable to find git in your PATH`'. This however does not happen if you are in Admin mode.

**Steps to reproduce**
Follow all steps to install Flutter on Windows, including installing Git before hand

Make sure that git works if you type it into Powershell as a regular user.
If not put the `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` (or your equivalent) folder into your Windows PATH
Open up Power shell as a regular / non-admin user then type `flutter doctor -v`. This causes the error: `Error: Unable to find git in your PATH`.

Now try opening in Admin mode and doing the same - it should work this time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I saw a comment at the very bottom of [this page](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2023/Jan/05/Fix-that-damn-Git-Unsafe-Repository), that suggested marking all your repos as 'safe' via

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

Not sure what the implication of doing so is but I went ahead and did it and now things are working properly!

Prior to this I had tried to make the flutter folder safe via:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory C:\Users\xxx\flutter\.git
git config --global --add safe.directory C:\Users\xxx\flutter\
```

but this hadn't worked.

Comment: This did not work for me, until I removed flutter (installed with chocolatey), GIT (installed by android studio) and reinstalled both by downloading the installer from the website. Still did not work, I tried again to add the flutter folder as safe folder and now it works.