# Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. with Git and flutter and dart

Tags: windows, flutter, git, powershell, dart

This is poupler error for many people.

I added flutter in Environment variable, Then when I write `flutter` in powerSell It's work, But when I write `dart` it's not work and gave me this Error `Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.`
I resured dart file is Already exists with flutter bin path, and I tried to write `dart` from it directory but same the error.

Then I installed Git in my OS Windows 11, After that when I write `dart` or `flutter` gave me the same error, but I can use `flutter` command into android studio termenal.

And every time I removing Git flutter is work and dart not work, And every time I Installing Git flutter and dart not work.

I trid to add D:\Program Files\Git\bin and D:\Program Files\Git\cmd and C:\WINDOWS\system32 to Environment variable, But does not affect, and trid install git in C partition, But does not affect
and tried this command `git config --global --add safe.directory C:/tools/flutter-base-dir`

Comment: You may have a permission issue.  You are installing as an Admin and the folder may have only Admin read/executable permission.  Most installation packages have option to install for one user and all users.  Some how the installation is not working correctly.   See : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git?force_isolation=true

Comment: See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75921194/45375) helps. If so, we can close your question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem.

just edit Flutter directory path to another and add it in Environment variable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).