# I cannot use flutter without admin permission in windows

Tags: flutter, git, powershell, environment-variables

When I try to run any flutter command, the terminal show an error: unable to find git in your path, however when I run as admin simply work

I did reed on the documentation that flutter folder can't be in Program Files or any other folder with low permissions, but my flutter folder is in the user directory;
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75921194/flutter-on-windows-unable-to-find-git-in-your-path-if-terminal-is-not-in-admi/75921195#75921195) suggested set flutter folder and "flutter.git" folder as safe directory. I did it, but doesnt work;
My env var are ok;

Comment: Presumably relevant background info is in [this blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2023/Jan/05/Fix-that-damn-Git-Unsafe-Repository).

Comment: reinstall git and when installing, make sure to add it to your system's path

Comment: @mklement0 i tried this before to create this topic and it's definitelly not solve my problem :( . I tried this blog solution too, but doesn't solve

Comment: Also note that your'e saying that setting "flutter folder and flutter.git folder as safe directory" didn't work, which the linked answer also acknowledges and states that the following _did_ work: `git config --global --add safe.directory '*'` Just to rule out the obvious: you tried the latter too?

Comment: @Texv I tried this twice, but didn't work