# Flutter doctor "Error: Unable to find git in your PATH." (Windows)

Tags: windows, flutter, git, environment-variables, flutter-doctor

Flutter and git are both installed in a folder (like E:\VigneshKannan\Flutter\bin and C:\Program Files\Git). I made sure that both users have full access in the security properties of that folder.

I added all these to the System Path Variable:

```
E:\VigneshKannan\Flutter\bin
C:\Windows\System32
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

When I run where git or where flutter, the correct paths are printed.
[where flutter and git path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLZbV.png)
But when I run flutter, it returns "Error: Unable to find git in your PATH." Why? How do I fix this?

when I run flutter doctor, it returns "Error: Unable to find git in your PATH." Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you restart your system after modifying the *PATH*? To make sure they are there, start a *Cmd* window and type there `set PATH` and see if they appear.

Comment: No! but the issues resolved after doing this.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75921195/12877810)